# GitHub doesn't recognize file encoding change

Tags: git, eclipse, encoding, pull-request

I'm using Eclipse and I had UTF-8 so all accents for the comments in the changed files were converted to some wrong symbols.

I need my files have cp-1252 so I went to eclipse preferences changed my encoding, corrected the accent letters, did a PR and Git still shows the wrong symbols coming. In Eclipse letters/accents are displayed fine, so even when I do "show difference" no differences are tracked. I tried to make :

```
[diff "win1252"]
    textconv = "iconv -f utf-8 -t windows-1252
```

But that didn't help. Is there a way to change encoding locally to make Git see the encoding differences?

Comment: Keep [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/)!